# How to make it so that objects don't pass through each other?

Tags: animation

How to make it so that objects don't pass through each other?
For example, when a character picks up an object, when a character rests on the wall, etc. 
Here is an example of the wrong animation:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, this kind of actions are made using Inverse Kinematics:
when the hand reaches the table you switch the arm from FK to IK, put the IK hand controller in the same position as reached by the FK hand controller so, in the following frames, the hand stays still as the arm is moving.

Comment: I studied it a little & I have problem. FK's & IK's armatures should be put in the same poses. But it's unreal. Also I know if to apply the modifier Copy Rotation to FK that it will repeat the position of IK. But I haven't found a way how to put IK in FK's pose. Is there a way how to quickly switch between IK & FK and that they repeated poses each other?

Comment: As far as I know it must be done manually, but, with a little of trials and errors, you can reach the result quite quickly, expecially using the double R rotation mode (select a bone, press R key Twice, adjust the rotation of the bone with up/down/left/right movements of the mouse). Also knowing the bone's  axes will help in the task: I.E. R Y Y will rotate every bone on their longitudinal axes. Consider also that you have the FK in one frame and the IK on the next, so a little movement is not only accepted, but desiderable.

Comment: Can you advice me a good tutorial about IK-FK, or maybe you can tell me how to make it? I just found out about IK-FK when you told me about it. I was looking for, but basically it was tutorials how to make the switch IK-FK. I found one tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8IsnFG9NUU&index=10&list=PL1CDAAF5EE1FF18C4), but the result isn't quite good: http://s019.radikal.ru/i637/1506/ae/7bbeb707c521.gif. Another tutorials I couldn't find. Help me please with this question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU for a simple rig using IK.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB this is an amazing serie about advanced rigging.